# Gradle: Cannot configure artifactory from an external build script

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am new to gradle and would like to access my artifactory repository from it. If I put all configurations into one build script, the build succeeds. Here are the relevant parts of my build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'artifactory'
}

// ...

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { 
            url 'http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins' 
        }

        maven {
            url artifactory_contextUrl + 'plugins-release'

            credentials {
                username = artifactory_user
                password = artifactory_password
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.16')
    }
}


artifactory {
    contextUrl = artifactory_contextUrl

    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
            maven = true
        }
    }

    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
            maven = true
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    // My dependencies ...
}

// Rest of the build script ...
```

Now, I would like to pull out the artifactory part into a separate gradle script for better organization. This is where the build goes wrong. Quite surprisingly, I get the following error even if I copy my build.gradle to foo.gradle, and change build.gradle to just contain the single line

```
apply from: 'foo.gradle'
```

The error is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/path/to/my/project/foo.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Plugin with id 'artifactory' not found.
```

In case this is not a bug, can anyone please explain this behavior of gradle's `apply from` and propose a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The `apply from` part is parsed once the build script is already configured, so telling Gradle where to find the plugins with specific ID is too late. You'll have to keep the `buildscript` part  in the script, or put it in the [init script](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html):

```
apply from : 'http://link.to/my/gradle.script'
```

Comment: Could use an example of how this would work in an init script. I tried, but couldn't get the init script to run and get things setup correctly.

Comment: Well, it's exactly what's section 60.5 is talking about. Example added.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fully qualified class name to apply the plugins in your helper script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
         jcenter() 
         mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.adaptc.gradle:nexus-workflow:0.5"
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.2.4"
    }
}
apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPublicationsPlugin
apply plugin: com.adaptc.gradle.nexusworkflow.NexusWorkflowPlugin
```

Note that Gradle won't find the plugins if you put quotes around the class name, as you would do normally with plugin names.

This is how I found the class name for the Artifactory plugin:

1. I downloaded the plugin which was thankfully [open source](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info).
2. I searched for the name of the plugin among the files and found
   `artifactory-puplish.properties`.
3. It contained the following
   property: `implementation-class=org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPublicationsPlugin`

The [source of nexus-workflow](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/plugins-gradle/tree/master/nexus-workflow) has no such properties file so I looked around until I found

```
plugins-gradle-master/nexus-workflow/src/main/groovy/com/adaptc/gradle/nexusworkflow/NexusWorkflowPlugin.groovy
```